# WiFi doesn't work after suspend on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: networking, network-manager, suspend, 18.10, surface

I have a *Surface Book* dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and most of the times when I close my laptop and open it again, the WiFi won't connect. It will see the available networks, but it won't be able to connect to them and on trying to connect after a few tries it says

> No Networks available.

The only way to fix it is to restart my computer.
Would love any help I can get...
I have tried most of the answers in other questions...

Comment: Running 'sudo service network-manager restart' doesn't fix the issue either.